# Flutter build failed with processDebugResources

Tags: android-studio, flutter-build

I followed following [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply) and get now following error while running my app:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
 This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

What information do you need more to solve this ussue?